# React ajax and jsx

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, reactjs, jsx

My array that I filled with my ajax request result will not appears in my react components unordered list.

When I do a console.log of the array I get:

[]
0
:
"Career"

1
:
"Middle College for Technology Careers"

2
:
"Careers New Zealand"

3
:
"Careers for Veterans 200"

4
:
"Northside Health Careers High School"

5
:
"Barbie's careers"

6
:
"Edward M. Kennedy Academy for Health Careers"

7
:
"The Careers Group, University of London"

8
:
"Careers advisor"

9
:
"Careers advisory service"

length
:
10

**proto**
:
Array[0]

When I call this array inside my react component it does not render. Here is my code below.

HTML

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

JS

```
// array that the titles will be loaded into
var response = [];

$.ajax({
    // request type ( GET or POST )
    type: "GET",

    // the URL to which the request is sent
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?",

    // data to be sent to the server
    data: {
        action: "query",
        format: "json",
        list: "search",
        srsearch: "careers",
        srwhat: "text",
        srprop: "timestamp",
        continue: "",
    },

    // The type of data that you're expecting back from the server
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    // Function to be called if the request succeeds
    success: function (jsondata) {
        for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.query.search.length; i++) {
            //console.log( jsondata.query.search[i].title );
            //pushes each result into the array named list
            response.push(jsondata.query.search[i].title);
        }
    },
});

console.log(response);

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        //var title = list;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <p>The world is full of oppurtunity</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>{response[0]}</li>
                    <li>Freedom</li>
                    <li>Lozve</li>
                    <li>Money</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    },
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("content"));
```

Here is a link to my code pen where all my code is, http://codepen.io/vhall_io/pen/vKQrQN/ . I inserted response[0] into the first li tag and it will not render. Please help me render this.

Comment: You're calling `render` before your ajax call returns. put `ReactDOM.render` after your for loop

Comment: thanks @azium this actually works.

Comment: No problem. Do you understand why it didn't work the previous way?

Comment: I believe so, to my understanding the unordered list was be created before the ajax call return the request. Once the ul element was create it couldn't be modified.

Comment: The UI element certainly can be changed using `this.state` and `this.setState`

Comment: It works if you call the react code inside the success of the ajax call and change response for other name... seems to be a reserved word.

Comment: I haven't learned much about 'state' yet. This also looks like a good solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update state. It wont render is you are adding it to variable. as it is ajax call so your html render first

Comment: That depends, if it's data that happens only once before anything, could potentially call `render` when the data arrives. Setting state is, of course, a good approach.

Comment: agree! I made statement according to your code. Ofcourse my statement was not general.

Comment: thanks! I went with @azium 's answer as it solved my problem well.