# Can Ajax (asynchronous JavaScript with xml) work with JSX properly

Tags: javascript, xml, reactjs, jsx

When I make an AJAX call from a React JSX page in any number of ways, it always results in a static page and is unable to have real time updates.

Is this unavoidable? Can you use AJAX with JSX properly or is it unable to work?

Besides the hack where you setstate(), thereby refreshing the component which is the same as just adding an iframe with a refresh button and telling the user to refresh the entire page or part of the page and watch the little chrome thingy loop which is a terrible experience.

```
$.ajax({
  // request type ( GET or POST )
  type: "GET",
  ...
  // the URL to which the request is sent
  url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?",

  // data to be sent to the server
  data: {
    action: 'query',
    format: 'json',
    list: 'search',
    srsearch: 'careers',
    srwhat: 'text',
    srprop: 'timestamp',
    continue: ''
  },

  // The type of data that you're expecting back from the 
  server
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  crossDomain: true,
  // Function to be called if the request succeeds
  success: function(jsondata) {

    for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.query.search.length; i++) {
      //console.log( jsondata.query.search[i].title );
      //pushes each result into the array named list
      response.push(jsondata.query.search[i].title);
    }

  }
});



console.log(response)


var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
　　　  //var title = list;
       return(
         <div>
          <h1>Hello World</h1>
          <p>The world is full of oppurtunity</p>
          <ul>
            <li>{response[0]}</li>
            <li>Freedom</li>
            <li>Lozve</li>
            <li>Money</li>
          </ul>
         </div>
      );
     }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("content"));
```

Comment: Despite its name, AJAX can work with any kind of content. Depending on what you mean by "static page", your issue can be any number of things: JSX being not compiled or unrendered, cache being "helpful"... We ask for code so that we can see what exactly is going on, kind of like why a doctor would look at an X-ray instead of being satisfied with "something's funny with my foot". Thus - show not only your code (how exactly you're using AJAX), but also what exactly you're getting from the server (a snippet would suffice) and what you'd expect to see instead.

Comment: I don't think there's any code, ever, of working jsx with Ajax because I've searched the entire internet for years for that.

Comment: it's definitely possible. We don't want to see the working code, we want to see how you are trying to make ajax call and how you are trying to use that in jsx. you can post a very basic snippet of your not working or impossible code as you said.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924562/react-ajax-and-jsx?r=SearchResults In this problem they failed to get Ajax to work properly and simply called setstate() which reloads the entire render() component, as if you refreshed the page.

Comment: https://react.rocks/tag/Realtime there are examples of realtime applications with demo and source code. so don't tell me it's not possible to make real-time applications with react.

Comment: Those arnet jsx and or not the question

Comment: In your code, you're getting JSONP from Wikipedia, not JSX. What does that have to do with your question? Is your question how to render a JSX file clientside, or that you can't get AJAX to deliver a file to you, or what? (if the first, check out [react-jsx](https://github.com/bigpipe/react-jsx). If the latter, we still have no idea what is wrong, as you haven't shown what you're getting and how it differs from what you expect.